# Opencv with pre-trained model

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, pre-trained-model

I'm getting this error: cv2.error:

> OpenCV(4.6.0) d:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layer_internals.hpp:110: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "NHWC_output" of type "DepthToSpace" in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::detail::LayerData::getLayerInstance'

when trying to read and use the pre trained model (.pb).

here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

esrgan = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('./models/EDSR_x4.pb')

def upscale_image(image):
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor=1/255.0)
    esrgan.setInput(blob)
    result = esrgan.forward()
    result = np.clip(result[0] * 255, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
    return result
```

Comment: Opencv doesnt support all layer types of the world. Try to find out what kind of layer type "DepthToSpace" is and whether you can replace it by something more common. You could also try to convert your model to ONNX, could be easier usable by OpenCV.